# Plus.PeopleApi.load() method results in CODE 7(N/W Error) in <Android 5.0

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-plus, google-plus-signin

```
    Plus.PeopleApi.load(mGoogleApiClient, listID).setResultCallback(this);
```

When I use the above code in a device >= 5.0 it works flawlessly, but, on a device below that. I get code 7 i.e. N/W error. Why is that?